# How can i prevent other folder from accessing using Responsive Filemanager 9

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, file-manager

I am using [this filemanager](http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/index.php) and my problem is I want to restrict the access of the folders. Because in my page there are multiple users and every user has their own folders. Is it possible?

**Controller part**

```
$data['file_explorer'] = base_url('assets/resources/filemanager/dialog.php?type=0');
```

**View**

```
<a data-toggle="modal"  href="javascript:;" data-target="#myModal" class="btn" type="button">Upload</a>
```

...

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="100%" height="500" src="<?php echo $file_explorer; ?>" frameborder="0" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; "></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes , Its possible 
Here is a simple tweak to achieve this .

Consider your uploads directory is ***uploads***
and you have ***user1*** , ***user2*** , ***user3*** as sub directories , So , in that case we will be setting the uploads path and current path in the **config.php** dynamically from the parameters which we will be passing while calling the **dialog.php**

In the filemanager/config/config.php 
Append these lines

```
if( isset( $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH']))
 {
   $config['upload_dir']   =  $config['upload_dir'] . $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH']."/" ;
   $config['current_path'] =  $config['current_path'] . $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH']."/" ;
}
```

In the filemanager/dialog.php
Find this line
      **$get_params = http_build_query($get_params);**
And just before that line add

```
  if(isset($_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH'])){
     $get_params['MY_UPLOAD_PATH'] = $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH'] ;
   }
```

Now change your variable

**$data['file_explorer'] = base_url('assets/resources/filemanager/dialog.php?type=0');**

to

```
 $data['file_explorer'] = base_url('assets/resources/filemanager/dialog.php?type=0&MY_UPLOAD_PATH=user1');
```

Just change the value of  the MY_UPLOAD_PATH param and the dialog.php will show only that particular directory .